# the geometrical interpretation of $n!$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

We solved a $4C2$ combination, which equals $6$, which means that $4$ points forming corners of a square can be combined as a pair in $6$ ways. So what does $4!$ mean in first place geometrically. $4!=4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$. My idea is they are the number of lines possible using given points, but they contradict in cases of $0!$ and $1!$.. enlightened ye, a poor lad.. thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See [Visualizing the factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383150/visualizing-the-factorial).